# spring security using jwt token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, rest-security

We are designing an application which can be accessible via both mobile app and web app.

Mobile app will get data using exposed REST API (we are using CXF). For web app, we are using Spring MVC, it will also get data from REST API. In both cases, we want to show data for the authenticated users. For authentication, we are using JWT token.

My question here is we are offering two ways of accessing data via REST or web, and both need authentication. How can we reuse our security code in both components.

URL for web component
http://localhost:8080/web/resource/

URL for REST API component
http://localhost:8080/rest/resource/

URL for authentication
http://localhost:8080/auth/

Initially, we thought of having two different filters for each component, i.e. web and REST. From each of them we'll make a REST call to authentication API for validating the token. One doubt with this approach is if user going through web, then with this design we are validating token twice. So the better would be calling to the authentication API from REST API, avoiding it in web because rest api will always going to make authentication call.

Is there any other better way to do the same?

Comment: I think you can just share the REST APIs between the web and mobile, and secure the API with JWT token.

Comment: Despite design, all REST call should be always authenticated. So if you return View using MVC you must do auth and for every REST call either. As @chenrui said you can use JWT token for web and adroid auth.

Comment: Thanks Chenrui & Mr Jedi